# Is file locking on a network drive of a windows server reliable?

Tags: c#, windows, network-programming

I have a C# .NET application and a sqlite database file that is hosted on a network share (probably windows server 2003).

The problem is that the faq of sqlite says that file locking can be [unreliable](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5).

So my question is whether it is only unreliable on nfs shares ([see this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255219/reliability-of-file-locking-on-network-files)) or also on SMB/CIFS shares which are used by windows server 2003?

In case that it is also unreliable on SMB/CIFS shares, I have these two workarounds:

Use temporary file for locking:

```
try
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create("lock.tmp", 1000,
           FileOptions.DeleteOnClose))
    {
        db.savechanges();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex) { /* retry later */ }
```

Use temporary directory creation for locking:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CreateDirectory(string lpPathName,
                                          IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);

if(CreateDirectory("lock.tmp", IntPtr.Zero))
{
    db.savechanges();
    Directory.Delete("lock.tmp");

} else { /* retry later */ }
```

Comment: Perhaps you've outgrown SQLite and is time to move to a database explicitly design for concurrent access?

Comment: It is only a small application for which I cannot force the client company to set up a sql server. Is there any alternative to such a server?

Comment: The problem is that the company wants to use the app in a manner that is beyond its original design. What is required is a cost/benefit analysis to find a workaround, maintain it and deal with other issues such as scale vs migrating to server-based database engine. It doesn't have to be SQL Server. It could be a free version of MySQL or PostgreSQL.